# Cross compile on C::B from linux to win miss wxwidgets codes?

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, codeblocks

On Ubuntu 13.10, x86, using CodeBlocks i've successed cross compile from unix to Windows using minigw. Tested on windows and got a console.

It will not work with wxwidgets. Works fine under ubuntu but it won't compile wxwidgets for minigw compiler.

I've done this: [Code::Blocks and Cross Compilers](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_and_Cross_Compilers) and with console works

But not works with wxwidgets. It thrown an error like:

```
-------------- Build: Release in testwindows (compiler: MiniGW compiler for windows)---------------

i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -pthread  -Wall  -O2  -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__   -I/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include  -c /data1/backup_config/codeblocks/Learn/testwindows/testwindowsApp.cpp -o obj/Release/testwindowsApp.o
i586-mingw32msvc-g++: unrecognized option '-pthread'
In file included from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/platform.h:293,
                 from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/defs.h:21,
                 from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/event.h:15,
                 from /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/app.h:20,
                 from /data1/backup_config/codeblocks/Learn/testwindows/testwindowsApp.h:13,
                 from /data1/backup_config/codeblocks/Learn/testwindows/testwindowsApp.cpp:10:
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/chkconf.h:23:30: error: wx/msw/chkconf.h: No such file or directory
```

Source code when thrown an error:

```
#elif defined(__WXMSW__)
#  include "wx/msw/chkconf.h"
#elif defined(__WXMAC__)
```

So, I've checked a file chkconf.h on /usr/include/wx/chkconfig.h and there it's exists. But, codeblocks by default offers into **#  include "wx/msw/chkconf.h"**

How to fix this problem to cross compile correctly using CodeBlocks and wxwidgets 2.8?

[image: error example]

Comment: Cross-compilation if for platforms which aren't capable of supporting the compiler. Cross-compiling to windows is just giving yourself a headache for no reason. So don't do it: Compile for windows on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is too late for you, but surely this may help someone else. So, here it goes.

First of all, you must install the correct toolchain (go to terminal and type):

```
sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

Then, you need to compile a "windows" version of wxWidgets on Ubuntu, using the windows toolchain. This is for the current wxWidgets version (3.0), but should work as well for previous ones. I assume also:

- The source code of wxWidgets is installed in home directory (~/wxWidgets-3.0.0).
- There is a directory ready to store the library in ~/LocalLibs/wx-3.0.0_win.
- You may change versions/paths if you like, modifying the commands below accordingly.
- All tools to compile (gcc and libraries) are already installed.

So, the process is as follows (on a terminal window):

```
cd ~/wxWidgets-3.0.0
mkdir build_win
cd build_win/
../configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc --build=i586-linux --with-mingw --disable-shared --prefix="$HOME/LocalLibs/wx-3.0.0_win"
make
make install
```

Then, you can check if all has gone well with:

```
"$HOME/LocalLibs/wx-3.0.0_win/bin/wx-config" --host=i586-mingw32msvc --static --cxxflags  --debug=yes --unicode=yes --version=3.0
```

If all is ok, it will show the libraries needed to cross-compile with wxWidgets.

Finally, the C::B part (personally, I prefer Codelite, but anyway). First of all, create a new compiler option (Settings -> Compiler) and copy or rename one of them.

Then, go to "Toolchain executables" and set as follows:

```
C Compiler:         i586-mingw32msvc-gcc
C++ Compiler:       i586-mingw32msvc-g++
Linker dynamic:     i586-mingw32msvc-g++
Linker static:      i586-mingw32msvc-ar
Resource compiler:  `~/LocalLibswx-3.0.0_win/bin/wx-config --host=i586-mingw32msvc --rescomp`
```

And, finally, in "Search directories":

```
Compiler:       /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/
Linker:         /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/
Resource:       /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/
```

I think this is all. After that you should be able to compile with wxWdigets using your new cross-compiler and produce windows executables easily and happily in Ubuntu.

Comment: Very nice tutorial and good guide. But, it's fail on `--host=i586-mingw32msvc`

Comment: @MarinSagovac are you sure that mingw32 is installed? Which CPU do you have? Could you please check the name of some *mingw32 directory under /usr? Use that directory name in the --host= part of the commands.